# How do I compile to arm64-v8a .so using Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a C++ file to a .so file using the Android NDK. I need help because I'm unsure of how to do this through Android Studio.

I looked online and I couldn't find anything regarding this issue. Can someone please give me instructions on how I can compile my C++ file to a arm64-v8a .so file?

Comment: [Android NDK - Android ABIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) and scroll down to __Generate code for a specific ABI__

Comment: @RichardCritten can you help me I’m not sure what to do. Can you give me instructions on what to do to compile to arm64-v8 .so?

Comment: [Android Studio - Add C and C++ code to your project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)